# inner join to get row with max column value

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, join, sql-order-by

I have been trying to get the value of rows where the column value is max.
but it's somehow not working. please help out a bit.

Let me explain the problem

table 1 name = agency
columns agency_id, agency_name

table 2 name = client
columns client_name, total_bill, agency_id

what i want to get is the client name, agency name and total_bill of the row
for which total_bill value is maximum.

here's the query I was using

```
SELECT a.agency_name 
FROM agency a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT agency_id, client_name, MAX(total_bill) total_bill FROM client GROUP BY agency_id ) c 
ON a.agency_id = c.agency_id;
```

could you tell me where I am going wrong with this?

I am getting this error  -

```
Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains 
nonaggregated column 'agency-app.client.client_name' which is not 
functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible
with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

do let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT client.name, agency.name, client.total_bill
FROM agency, client 
WHERE agency.agency_id=client.agency_id 
AND client.total_bill=(SELECT MAX(total_bill) FROM client)
```

Comment: Thanks. this really fixed it for me. so I didnt need to use any group by at all then.

Comment: You have to use group by when you want to aggregate values, for example if the client uses multiple agencies and you want the maximum sum of total_bill for the clients in all the agencies they used, in this case you have to group by client_name to compute the sum of total_bill then finding the maximum of this sum.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the overall top customer, you can just join, order and limit:

```
select 
    a.agency_name,
    c.client_name,
    c.total_bill
from agencies a
inner join clients c on c.agency_id = a.agency_id
order by c.total_bill desc
limit 1
```